# String comparaison difference between two sentences

Tags: java

please can you tell me exactely what is the difference between 
this

```
if(myString.equals("test")) { }
```

And

```
if("test".equals(myString)) { }
```

Comment: The first one will throw a NPE is myString is null while the second one will evaluate to false. This is also called Yoda conditions. There's the same example on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myString` is `null`, you have

```
null.equals("test")   -->   NullPointerException

"test".equals(null)   -->   false
```

(If `myString != null` the expressions are equivalent.)

Answer (score 0):

there are no difference unless `mystring` is null

I usually follow the 2nd way

```
if("test".equals(myString)){ }
```

the reason is if mystring is null then 1st way will give me null pointer exception.

However in 2nd way is `mystring` comes null then also your application wont stop(due to null pointer exception) as it will return false